# Says Transaction not executed but the funds still went through

Tags: transactions, wallets, wallet-transfer, wallet-contracts

Mac Ethereum wallet says "transaction not executed" but the funds still went through:

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x11ac91b6aac99eb02afe078b8786a9f1672929f65c73ee68e51b9e0ccc91036a

[image]

But my everything was transferred..
From account has a 0 balance: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x3a98a87557dbd81d94153188d83251513890bb5d
To account has a increased balance:
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x48cbde71d09ba63b768d94b50cb7160cf1188705

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you feel your question has been answered, could you please mark it so other users know :)

Answer (score 0):

If the transaction went through and everything is working as expected then there is more likely a bug in the Mist wallet.

Please raise an issue on their [Github repository](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues).

However, I did find similar users who have had the same issue as you. In short, their advice is:

> Delete the whole database and start synchronising everything again. It then works.

Please see the following issue for more information: [Issue 1408](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/1408)

Hope this helps.